# Unable to execute: Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell

I'm attempting to use the PowerShell ISE on a Win 2012 Standard Server.

I followed the steps here (http://sharepointpromag.com/blog/powershell-and-sharepoint-step-1-loading-dlls-and-snap-ins) to add the SharePoint Snapin which worked on my DEV box but in my TEST environment I'm having some strange behavior.

This lists all of the assemblies without any issue.

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | ForEach-Object { Split-Path $_.Location -Leaf } | Sort
```

I load Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell with this assembly and verify it with the command above. However, I have to explicitly load each DLL.  If I use "Microsoft.SharePoint" as the value it does not load the PowerShell assembly.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell")
```

This does not display any values, SharePoint or otherwise which if found the strangest part.

```
Get-PSSnapin
```

This fails which makes sense, since there are not Snapins listed about.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

On another note, I'm able to execute the SharePoint Powershell console without an issue.

**Question:**
How can I add the SharePoint Snapin in the PowerShell ISE?
How can I debug why no PSSnapins appear to be registered?

Comment: What version of SharePoint and what version of PowerShell is in use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before you can do anything with PowerShell ISE, you need to make sure that (1) You are running PowerShell ISE as an Administrator and (2) that the execution policy is set in such a way that you can execute scripts.

Open SharePoint Management Shell and run

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

If you get `RemoteSigned`, `Unrestricted` or `Bypass` you can safely continue. RemoteSigned means that you can't run scripts that are downloaded from the another server or the internet unless it is signed. If you download files to run in PowerShell ISE, set the execution policy to unrestricted, like this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

If all works as expected, run PowerShell ISE as an Administrator. Then try to load the SharePoint.PowerShell with the following:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
```

When that has loaded, try another command, such as

```
Get-SPManagedAccount
```

If you receive no error messages, then you have SharePoint.PowerShell loaded. If not, run

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
```

and read the error messages. Copy the first line of the error received and try to search for it. Still in trouble? Update your answer with the error message, and I'll try to help if you notify me in a comment.

Comment: Thanks Benny , your solution works for me.
You saved my life ;)

Comment: Setting the execution policy to `unrestricted` is way too open for what you are doing

Comment: @KolobCanyon when done one reset the execution policy back to its original state

Comment: Isn't `Windows.SharePoint.PowerShell` signed though?

Comment: @KolobCanyon Defult setting for any installed Windows Server is complete lockdown - thus one have to enable/activate features to use

Comment: @BennySkogberg yes, i know, I guess now that I re-read you do mention remotesigned. That block of code should contain `RemoteSigned` instead of `Unrestricted` just because people will copy paste that

Answer (score 1):

It seems like, from your description, if you ran this:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
```

it would have failed, because `Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"` by itself failed.  So I don't know why that other answer was marked as the answer, unless it was because of your execution policy.  But the code above (the only other difference between what you did and that other answer) does not help you load `Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` if you could not load it through just `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell`, alone.

You would have to run your script on a SharePoint server, where that DLL exists in the GAC.  Or load it into the GAC on the workstation where you are running the script, presumably.  To load it into Powershell after doing that, you are correct in running this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell")
```

and then seeing if it has been loaded with:

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | ForEach-Object { Split-Path $_.Location -Leaf }
```

The one thing you forgot was getting the DLL into the GAC (C:\Windows\assembly), to begin with, it sounds like, to me.