# Can I add the sharepoint module to powershell? 2010 / 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, powershell

I apologize if this has been answered but I couldn't find any answers to my question.
I want to practice the power shell commands for Sharepoint (either 2010 or 2013)
but I can't seem to find a download of the module anywhere.

---

Do I need to run power shell or connect powershell remotely to the sharepoint server itself?
It seems odd that there are other modules you can install but sharepoint doesn't seem to be one of them.

---

I am aware of going on the server and running the "Sharepoint Management Shell" but I would like to have the powershell ISE on my laptop to have the module, if possible.
Is this even possible or am I stuck doing everything on the server?

---

Comment: You mean this? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/86122/627. Note that in 2013 you don't need any conditionals, just calling `Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"` every time should work wonders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different methods for this.  You can run issues commands from your laptop to your computer via invoke-command and just pass over the command you want to return and the output is returned locally.

TechNet Reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx

A more advanced method is initiate a remote session and then export that session with selected remote cmdlets.  This saves a pseudo copy of select module commands on your machine along with the session information so that when you run that command it can create the session back to the host automatically.

TechNet Reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849943.aspx

Don Jones a PowerShell MVP has a free eBook over at PowerShell.org called "Secrets of PowerShell Remoting" it targets PowerShell 2.0 but the information is still valid.  Here is the link:
http://powershell.org/wp/ebooks/

**Edit**
I forgot to mention the most important part.  It is not possibly to run PowerShell module locally unless you have installed SharePoint.  The module requires the .NET assemblies that are installed with the application.